# What exactly happens in the queues when a congested network applies back pressure ?

Tags: qos

During Congestion in a network switch HW ,for examplewhen  a shaping rate to the interface that imposes a speed limit lower than the maximum interface line speed .
The concept of back pressure is applied . Who back pressures whom and what is the exact behavior inside the network transmit queue.

Comment: Switches have very small queues, and when a switch queue is full, it starts dropping traffic.When you are using shaping, you probably mean on a router.

Comment: From your question: *Who back pressures whom and what is the exact behavior inside the network transmit queue.*  Not all switches use back-pressure from egress to ingress interfaces; even among switches that do, there is no guarantee that they all do it the same way.   As such please specify what switch model you're talking about.  For now, I am voting to close as too ambiguous.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, ECN provides an explicit means @ L3 for a signaling of link congestion.  On certain L2 transports there are also mechanisms that can be engaged when buffers fill - in frame relay there's the BECN/FECN mechanism.  In certain flavors of ATM (read: ABR) there's a live feedback mechanism to both signal congestion and even adjust provisioned PVC levels.

There are also flow control mechanisms in traditional Ethernet - 802.3x.  This is a MAC-layer mechanism that can be issued that will halt all traffic until the pause status is lifted.  This is most commonly seen nowadays in certain storage appliances.  As above, though, this is strictly a L2 construct and only operates on a hop-by-hop basis.

In modern Ethernet - very specifically the suite of protocols known as DCB (Data Center Bridging) there are mechanisms to both segregate different types of traffic into different forwarding queues (most crucially to identify lossless traffic - generally FCoE) as well as specific control messages sent at MAC layer to turn on flow control on a per-queue basis.  The idea here is to proactively pause traffic for queues that can tolerate loss, thus protecting lossless traffic.  The mechanism by which this operates is similar to 802.3x but is, in practice, massively more useful.

Finally - at L4 - TCP is probably overwhelmingly the most common point at which flow control and back-pressure occurs.  The mechanism here, of course, is sliding window.  When congestion occurs and packets are dropped TCP will adapt the rate at which packets are retransmitted (and, in turn, the rate at which subsequent data is sent).

Answer (score -1):

In IP world Explicit Congestion Notification would kick in.
All about ECN you can find in [RFC3168](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3168) or [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Explicit_Congestion_Notification)

Comment: I would love to know who is upvoting answers like this; sadly, you don't yet seem to address key points of the question, like this: *Who back pressures whom and what is the exact behavior inside the network transmit queue.*